# How to open ms access form or show msgbox from webbrowser control

Tags: ms-access, webbrowser-control

I have a ms access application. I put a webrowser conrol on my ms access form and I want to do some works(for example show msgbox, open form or report, excecute a command and etc from links or buttons on webbrowser control)
Is there a way for this?

Comment: Yes. Design a _web page_ with the hyperlinks and buttons you wish, host it somewhere, and open it in the browser control.

Comment: I don't want to design a webpage. Only I need to know is it posibble to do commands directly from link webbrowser control on form access instead of do it from  form

Comment: This makes no sense. You wish _to do commands directly from link webbrowser control_, but you don't want to design the web page. A full stop it is.

Comment: Yes. you are right. I did it. Now, is it possible to put some code among HTML code to open form or report or other coomands or no?

Comment: No. Access has no web interface.